# Op-Amp Dual Supply Generation

Tags: power-supply, power, operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

I am planning to generate +/-9V using LT1026 as shown.

[image: LT1026]

These configuration is shown in datasheet of LT1026 Charge pump        (page 5).

But my question is if I add one more IC in parallel if I need more current to supply more OP-AMP IC's, Is it good option?
What precaution I can take to implement precise noise-free circuit? Please suggest. Should I remove the 1K bleed resistors to save current?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use 2 batteries?

Comment: If I were you, I would go for "virtual ground": Just two resistors and one electrolytic capacitor instead of two ICs.

Comment: @ Rohat, please explain using schematics... its difficult for me to understand. :)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, This is used in bulk qty.. so battery is not good option. Thanks,